# Substitution of Variable in Limits

Tags: calculus, limits

So Here's the Question

$$F(x)=\frac{x^2\sin(\frac1x)+2x}{(1+x)^\frac1x -e} \quad \text{then}\quad \lim_{x \to 0}{F(x)=}$$

I tried this Question by Substituting $x = \frac1y$ Where $\lim_{y \to \infty}$
But still in the outcome there are $2$ forms coming out which are $\frac00$ and $\frac \infty\infty$. I also came across an alternate solution which is by substituting $x$ as $\frac1x$ and no limits specified for $x$. Can anyone explain the logic behind the alternate solution and even how to proceed further with my approach. Thanks :)

Comment: are you allowed to use Taylor expansion?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Well didn't thought for that but would it be useful in solving the question in less time ?

Comment: have you tried to expand the denominator?

Comment: @SineoftheTime Using taylor expansion ?

Comment: yes, using Taylor

Comment: Your approach and the "alternative" solution are the same. This is because the name you use for the variable of the limit is irrelevant: I can always do the transformation $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and then "change the name of the variable" with a new transformation $x=y$. If that is confusing, keep doing it your way :). For the next step, as you have a result of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, you can use [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: @cjferes Got it ! Thanks a lot for the help :)